# Does log4j2 support globs or regular expression in logger names in config files?

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I have many logger names following some naming convention like in the following examples:

- org.example.unique_phrase.foo
- org.example.unique_phrase.bar
- org.example.foo.unique_phrase.bar
- org.example.bar.unique_phrase.foo

The goal is to configure one file appender for all packages/logger names containing `unique_phrase`. At the same time I would like to keep the possibility for more fine grained configs with possible different appenders for different packages of the above example. The only solution I know of is really configuring all individual logger names/packages with the same appender. Would be easier if logger names would support some concept of globs or regular expressions, so one might only use the following name:

- org.example.*.unique_phrase.*

Is something like that possible, either out-of-the-box or possibly some plugin or ...?